# flutter column widget receive null about height in runtime

Tags: flutter

```dart
 AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    height: isExpanded == true ? 100 : 0,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        GridView.extent(
                            maxCrossAxisExtent:
                                SetDeviceRatio.safeBlockHorizontal * 30,
                            children: List.generate(foodCode.length, (index) {
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 50,
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[Text(foodCode[index])],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            })),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

I made code like this  and in runtime it said

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#fce1e relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    AnimatedContainer 
lib/MainUI/MainCategoryUI.dart:71
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The method '>' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: >(1e-10)
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Column
```

when i delete Column it works well but i don't get it why.
in column there is gridview and each row has same height and can calculate how long height need
so i thought column didn't need height variable.

Comment: Even If you put set the shrinkwrap in your grid view = true, It will take as much height as it needs. But, still, your animated container allows a height of 100 when it is expanded. The column tries to wrap around the grid view taking a vertical height of perhaps more than 100. It will still throw an error with shrinkWrap on. Why do you need the column though?

Comment: thanks i didn't think about shrinkwrap that 100 height of animatedContainer was just test height and that was not issue in this problem and yeah i want some text above girdview so i add column

Comment: Give it a try! Though, I feel like the column will still cause conflicts even after shrinkWrap as it will try to take as much height as the grid view which might exceed even the screen height. You can give slivers a try if you need headers and all.

Comment: In my case it's work but there is alarm about warning so yeah i think i need to take slivers thanks